# How to insert data in mysql database using ionic 2? I have tried many solutions but result is sill same

Tags: php, mysql, ionic-framework, ionic2, http-post

I have problem to insert data using http.post request in ionic 2 framework. But it does'nt send data to my restful api but increases row in mysql database with empty fields. I have tried many solutions but no result found and still getting same error. Here is my code for posting data.

**setting.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-setting',
  templateUrl: 'setting.html',
})
export class Setting {
  name: string;
  lname: string;
  email: string;
  pass: string;
  gender: string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public http: Http) {
  }
  insertData() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let postParams =  {
      name: this.name,
      last_name: this.lname,
      email: this.email,
      gender: this.gender,
      password: this.pass,
    } 
    this.http.post("http://localhost:9090/restexample/RestController.php?view=insert", JSON.stringify(postParams), options)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data['_body']);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);// Error getting the data
      });
  }
}
```

**setting.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Setting</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Last Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lname"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="gender"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Email</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="pass"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button block color="primary" (click)="insertData();">Insert Data</button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**Mobile.php**

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

class Mobile {

    function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users", "root", "");
        $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    }

    public function getAllusers(){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users"); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        $this->mobiles= $stmt->fetchAll();          
        return $this->mobiles;
    }

    public function getUser($id){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where id = '$id'"); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }   

    public function delUser($id){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("delete FROM users where id = '$id'"); 
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    public function insUser(){

        $data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `last_name`, `gender`, `email`, `password`, `ip_address`, `avatar`) VALUES (\"{$data['name']}\", \"{$data['last_name']}\", \"{$data['gender']}\", \"{$data['email']}\", \"{$data['password']}\", \"{$data['ip_address']}\", \"{$data['avatar']}\");"); 
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    public function updUser($id){
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users
SET name = \"{$_POST['name']}\", last_name= \"{$_POST['last_name']}\", gender = \"{$_POST['gender']}\" ,  email = \"{$_POST['email']}\", password = \"{$_POST['password']}\", ip_address= \"{$_POST['ip_address']}\", avatar= \"{$_POST['avatar']}\ WHERE id = $id;"); 
        $stmt->execute();
    }           

}
?>
```

**Error on browser:**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved my problem by change data into single string:**

```
let postParams ='name='+ this.name + '&last_name=' + this.lname + '&email=' + this.email + '&gender=' + this.gender +
    '&password=' + this.pass + '&ip_address=' + this.ip + '&avatar=' + this.avatar;
```

**And store values in multiple $_POST variables instead of single $_POST['data'] variable:**

```
public function insUser(){
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `last_name`, `gender`, `email`, `password`, `ip_address`, `avatar`) VALUES (\"{$_POST['name']}\", \"{$_POST['last_name']}\", \"{$_POST['gender']}\", \"{$_POST['email']}\", \"{$_POST['password']}\", \"{$_POST['ip_address']}\", \"{$_POST['avatar']}\");"); 
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

But still looking for the proper solution to send an object...

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code is looking for 'data' index inside the $_POST array (in the insUser() function), so in your ts file you need to put your post params inside a data attribute:

```
let postParams = { data: {
  name: this.name,
  last_name: this.lname,
  email: this.email,
  gender: this.gender,
  password: this.pass,
}};
```

This will resolve the current error but it would still not work because I see that the insert query is looking for 'ip_address' and 'avatar' but you are not providing them in your postParams.

Comment: `let postParams = { data: {
      name: this.name,
      last_name: this.lname,
      email: this.email,
      gender: this.gender,
      password: this.pass,
      ip_address: this.ip_address,
      avatar: this.avatar

    }};` still same error occured, undefined index :data

Comment: Can you print_r your $_POST before the error line and post the result here ?

Comment: Change your headers to 'Content-Type', 'application/json'